# After installing Cpanel php scripts printed instead of executed

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, centos7

i recently installed latest version of Cpanel. installation completed successfully. after installation i changed the docmentRoot from `/user/local/apache/htdocs` to `/home/myuser/public_html` vai `Service Configuration >Apache Configuration >Include Editor > Pre Virtual Host Include`

```
<VirtualHost 100.113.218.68:80 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName example.net

    ServerAlias cpanel.* whm.* webmail.* webdisk.* cpcalendars.* cpcontacts.*

    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/public_html
   .
   .
```

then when i run the index.php as the following `http://example.net/index.php` content is :

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

php script printed instead of executing.
i checked /etc/http/logs/error_log and this is the content:

```
[Sun Jan 03 14:37:19.701372 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 41895] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jan 03 14:37:22.001720 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 42750] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/local/apache/bin/suexec)
[Sun Jan 03 14:37:22.001833 2016] [:notice] [pid 42750] ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.0 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Sun Jan 03 14:37:22.001840 2016] [:notice] [pid 42750] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.5.2"; loaded version="1.5.2"
[Sun Jan 03 14:37:22.001847 2016] [:notice] [pid 42750] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.36 "; loaded version="8.36 2014-09-26"
[Sun Jan 03 14:37:22.001854 2016] [:notice] [pid 42750] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Sun Jan 03 14:37:22.001857 2016] [:notice] [pid 42750] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.2"
[Sun Jan 03 14:37:22.001861 2016] [:notice] [pid 42750] ModSecurity: Status engine is currently disabled, enable it by set SecStatusEngine to On.
[Sun Jan 03 14:37:23.005187 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 42751] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 03 14:37:23.005255 2016] [core:notice] [pid 42751] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd'
```

in my httpd.conf file this is only the loaded modules

`LoadModule bwlimited_module modules/mod_bwlimited.so`

Comment: Why you changed document root to user? I think it's not correct way of work with Cpanel. Document root of cpanel apache it's for internal use such, redirects to 403,404,405, moving pages, ... If download instead show, it's because Apache not connect with suExec on this directory... IMHO (.htacess, incorrect suexec) What model use ? SuPHP, cgi, fast-cgi, other..?